# Sybase ULtralite DB and iOS Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Is it possible to use Sybase ULtralite DB as the storage medium for Core Data instead of SQlite?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, although it might not be worth the effort:

[Atomic Store Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AtomicStore_Concepts/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004521)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using either the Atomic store or the new Incremental Store. As @sosborn suggested though, there is very little point and it is not worth the effort.  If you are dealing with syncing with a server you are better off transferring the data in an intermediate format like JSON.

Comment: Thanks you for the fast reply. In my case I have to go with Sybase Mobilink Sync solutions.

Comment: Is there any open source Sync solution framework for iOS and Android?. I didn't find any. If not then I am interested in starting a open-source project. Anybody willing to join?

Comment: This is not the place to ask for that.