# Modifying the ultralite DB through my code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to iphone development . I want to create a simple Sybase Ultralite DB in my system(localy), and want to modify it through my code . i.e I want to perform insert,delete and update through my code.I followed many links but couldn't find a proper answer . There is no proper tutorial for integrating Sybase Ultralite ,where as for SQLite there are many . Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Do you mean Sybase Ultralite? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631241/sybase-ultralite-db-and-ios-core-data

Comment: Yea Sybase Ultralite . sorry for not being clear. I will edit it.